# Date Formatter - String to Date 2012-02-05T00:00:00+00:00

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdateformatter

I am attempting convert this string "2012-02-05T00:00:00+00:00" into a more attractive, nicely formatted string like "Tuesday March 5, 2012.

I have an example that I'm working from:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20081122";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateStr);
[dateFormat release];
```

How would I accommodate for the date format "2012-02-05T00:00:00+00:00" using similar code above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i see your time "2012-02-05T00:00:00+00:00", I think you are printing a "NSDate" into your console. In that time "2012-02-05" is a date and "T00:00:00+00:00" is a time. So when you need to use date like this,

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2012-02-05";
```

you have to format like this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

If you want to convert the date component into as you liked try this

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2012-02-05";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
NSLog(@"%@",dateStr);
```

You can even do like this to convert the current date into as you like.

```
// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; //for current date  
NSLog(@"%@",dateStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do by using -

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss z"];
```

Comment: this code should work. But I'd use `HH` instead of `hh` for hours. `HH` represents a 24-hour format, whereas `hh` is 12-hour

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but doing NSLog(@"Date: %@", date); is returning (null)

Comment: where are you using the above format, you should use @"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss z" instead of @"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"

Comment: I have tried that but it still returns (null). I thought @"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY" was the output format anyway?